# a command to reconsult user-mode stream

Tags: prolog

Please, what command do I put in the following situation:

```
[user].
not_a_correct_procedure(X,Y):- f([...])
```

after trying it I have to change it for it is not correct.

If I just type `[user]` again it gives a redefinition error. Nor the `?- abort.` or `?- break.` works. 
Do you know a command that would do good in this case?

Comment: You can assume the error is just a warning. The redefinition will work AFAIK

Comment: It's actually a warning, not an error. Your new definition should be in place even though you got a warning.

Comment: Why don't you write your code in a text file and then compile it?

Comment: I was about to ask more or less the same question. What I would like to know is if there is a commando to completely wipe out [user] space. I hope someone do answer this very question and I'll refrain to ask another too much similar.